# Count number of operations in algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have to count exact number of operations that algorithm performs:

```
count = 0
for( i=0 ; i<=10 ; i++ ) 
    for( i=0 ; i<=10 ; i++ ) 
            count += (i + 10) / 2
```

I understand that its complexity is `O(1)`. Exact number of CPU operations equals to:
`10 * 10 (outer and inner cycle)  + 100 (s += i + 10) + 100 (sum/2) + 1 (declaration of count variable)`? Or I am wrong?

How can I count them?

Comment: Why would you want to count the exact number of CPU operations? The complexity of an algorithm is not computed using exact numbers, moreover, there will be more actual CPU operations and the count depends on the compiler used.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing exactly what an "operation" is. Perhaps on systems where registers are zeroed out at the beginning of programs by default, `count = 0` is actually a no-op and doesn't count towards total operations. If this is a homework assignment, ask your teacher for clarification. If it's not a homework assignment, don't worry about it too much -- just knowing the complexity should be a useful enough measurement on its own.

Comment: The complexity is O(1). There's no `n` in sight, or any variable for that matter.

Comment: That's why the complexity theory is based on abstract computers, such as Turing's machines, where there is a clear definition of an operation.

Comment: Also, this might be a trick question - notice how the inner loop and outer loop use the same variable. Depending on your language, this may mean that the `count += ` line only executes ten times.

Comment: @Kevin it is, see the answers and comments below..

Comment: Since it is only counting of operations, regardless of the input data, it is not related to the complexity theory at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... Did you deliberately use `i` for both loops?  (making the outer loop pointless)?

Assuming you meant to use different variables:

- in the first `for()` loop, we have one assignment, 11 comparisons and 11 increments (and yes, 0 to 10 is 11)  For a total of 23 "operations".
- In the second `for()` loop, we have the same 23 operation, performed 11 times each, for 253 operations.
- in the body, we have two addition, a divison and an assignment, for 4 operation repeated 121 times, for a total of 484.

  23 + 253 + 484 = **760 "operations".**

UPDATE:
 Now, working with the idea the using the same variable was intentional:

- in the first `for()` loop, we have one assignment, one comparison and one increment, for a total of 3 "operations".
- In the second `for()` loop, we have the same 23 operation (see above), performed once.
- in the body, we have two addition, a divison and an assignment, for 4 operation repeated 11 times, for a total of 44.

  3 + 23 + 44 = **70**

Note, however, all operations are not equal.  A divison will take much longer than an increment.

Comment: No, I meant to use only one variable - i (yes, i know that inner loop is quite pointless).

Comment: This is however only one of possible definitions of an operation. A CPU operations are also jumps from the end of one iteration cycle to the beginning of another, reading of the instructions, allocation of space for storing variables, reading/writing variable values, etc..

Comment: Why the number of operations in inner loop is 44 but to 44 * 11 (number of iterations in outer loop)?

Answer (score 1):

To count every operation we  count:

```
count = 0                         // 1
for( i=0 ; i<=10 ; i++ )          // 1 => (i = 0) + 1 => (i <= 10)
    for( i=0 ; i<=10 ; i++ )      // 1 => (i = 0) + 11 => (i <= 11) + 11 => (i++)
        count += (i + 10) / 2     // 11* (1 => (i+10) + 1 => (/2) + 1 => (+=))
```

Total count of operations = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 11 + 11 + 11*(1 + 1 + 1) = 59

Edit: note that since you're using i in both loops, you will not run the outer loop.

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that the last line will be performed 11 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to have a different variable for the inner loop, then you are right, the complexity is O(n^2).

What I was thought was to always start with the inner-most loop. How many times would it iterate? In this case, it would perform 10 iterations.

Then focus on the outer loop: how many times does that one iterate? It also performs 10 iterations, and in each iteration the inner loop has 10 iterations.